# awk - How to get only the matching portion of a regex

Tags: regex, awk

I have code like this

```
echo abc | awk '$0 ~ "a\(b\)c" {print $0}'
```

What if I only wanted what's in the parentheses instead of the whole line? This is obviously very simplified, and there is really a lot of awk code so I don't want to switch to sed or grep or something. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136366/how-to-use-non-capturing-groups-in-grep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do it in the `pattern` part, you must do it inside the `action` part with the `match()` function:

```
echo abc | awk '{ if ( match($0, /a(b)c/, a) > 0 ) { print a[1] } }'
```

It yields:

```
b
```

Comment: You absolutely can do it outside of the action part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern/4673336#4673336

Comment: BTW, this is a GNU awk extension.

Comment: @glennjackman: Good one. I didn't know you could use an array from the `pattern` to the `action. I upvoted yours in the other side.

Comment: If there's a match, the return value of `match` is true, so the action block will execute.

Comment: This is the correct answer but not for msysgit which uses GNU Awk 3.0.4: `match() cannot have 3 arguments`. GnuWin32's gawk 3.1.6 seems to work fine though. I've marked your answer as correct since it appears to be correct in other cases.

Comment: @user2672807 Those are both very old versions of gawk, you should consider installing a newer one as you're missing a lot of very useful functionality.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
$ echo abc | awk '{print gensub(/a(b)c/,"\\1","")}'
b
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, that's a good alternative. match() doesn't work for msysgit's gawk so I'll probably use something similar to what you suggested.