# Bash shell(grep) equivalent of this python regular expression?

Tags: regex, bash

I have written a regular expression to match hyphenated word in python

```
regexp = r"[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*"
```

It matches words with zero or more hyphens. For e.g. abc,acd-def,x-y-y etc.
However, I can't find this grouping operator ?: for shell(for instance using with grep). It seems to me that this is a feature of python regex only not standard regex.

Can anyone please tell me how to write the same regex in shell?

Comment: It is a standard [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). If you can't use it in bash, use a capturing group: `[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*`.

Comment: Remove the non-capturing group or use the `-P` flag for grep. `grep -Po "[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*" file`

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [How to use non-capturing groups in grep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136366/how-to-use-non-capturing-groups-in-grep), but have a slight doubt...

Answer (score 3):

`(?:pattern)` matches `pattern` without capturing the contents of the match. It is used with the following `*` to allow you to specify zero or more matches of the contents of the `( )` without creating a capture group. This affects the result in python if you used something like `re.search()`, as the `MatchObject` would not contain the part from the `(?: )`. In grep, the result isn't return in the same way, so can just remove the `?:` to use a normal group:

```
grep -E '[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*' file
```

Here I'm using the `-E` switch to enable extended regular expression support. This will output each line matching the pattern - you can add the `-o` switch to only print the matching parts.

As mentioned in the comments (thanks), it *is* possible to use back-references (like `\1`) with grep to refer to previous capture groups inside the pattern, so technically the behaviour is being changed slightly by removing the `?:`, although this isn't something that you're doing at the moment so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Ah yes, in the pattern itself I guess it does. Good point, will edit.

Comment: Can you explain your second point, since the comment you are referring to has been removed?

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression doesn't "match hyphenated word" - it matches words made up of `[-a-z]` where the first and last character must be in `[a-z]`.  I.e. it matches `[a-z]` (one-letter words) or `[a-z][-a-z]*[a-z]`.

Your question is ambiguous - `bash` normally deals with *wildcard expressions*; `grep` can process *regular expressions*.

- #### Bash

  This cannot be done with wilcards.  You may use the `=~` operator inside `[[ ]]` brackets: `[[ $string =~ [a-z]|[a-z][-a-z]*[a-z] ]]`.
- #### Grep

  You can combine two regexes with `|` like so: `[a-z]|[a-z][-a-z]*[a-z]`.

Reading between the lines of your question - "to match hyphenated word" sounds more like you want a regexp like `[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)+` so that there's at least one `-` in your match.