# RegEx substitution works in Ruby gsub, but not with sed

Tags: ruby, regex, sed, zsh, semantic-versioning

I'm trying to strip prefixes from a SemVer, i.e, making `1.2.3-prefix.42` into `1.2.3`.

I'm using this RegEx found in https://github.com/mojombo/semver/issues/32#issuecomment-7663411:

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:-([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?(?:\+([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?
```

When using Ruby's `gsub` method, it works:

```
puts '1.2.3-alpha.4'.gsub(/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:-([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?(?:\+([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?$/, '\1')
# => 1.2.3
```

But when using `sed` form the terminal it doesn't:

```
$ echo '1.2.3-alpha.4' | sed -e 's/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:-([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?(?:\+([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?$/\1/g'
$ 1.2.3-alpha.4
```

What am I missing?

I'm using zsh on Mac OS X.

Thanks

Comment: I believe non-capturing groups (`(?: ... )`) aren't available in sed. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823864/how-do-you-specify-non-capturing-brackets-in-sed

Comment: While capture groups are probably you're main problem, I'd be surprised if the stock install of `sed` in OSX supports `\d`, use `[0-9]` instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're more comfortable with ruby, you can use it like sed:

```
echo '1.2.3-prefix.42' | ruby.exe -ne 'puts $_.sub /[^\d.].+/, ""'
#=> 1.2.3
```

I don't think you really want to learn sed if you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks @pguardiario. After all "the easiest way to solve a problem is not to have it in the first place."

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make strings like `1.2.3-prefix.42` become `1.2.3` you don't have to prepare such complicated `sed` expression.

Just check if the string starts with a combination of three numbers separated by dots and catch it. Then, print it back:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]).*/\1/' <<< "1.2.3-prefix.42"
1.2.3
```

Since the rest of the patterns you are using in the Ruby expression use `?` we can assume they are optional, so I am not including them.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, but although correct, your answer doesn't work on OS X's stock `sed`.

Comment: @mokagio that's weird! I don't have such version here, you may want to add the output to see what is missing to make it BSD compatible.