# Regex: Match a pattern followed by only one space but not 2 or more spaces or EOF

Tags: regex, bash, scripting

Input string:

```
1234 5678 9101 1234
2999 5178 9101 2234
9999 5628 9201 1232
8888 3678 9101 1232
```

The input string above has spaces after *1st*, *2nd* and *3rd* line. Each line after the last digit has spaces and then the new line starts except the last line.

The last line ends at the last character(digit '2') and has nothing else after that.

**Required Match**: I want to match only the first three block of digits in each line(match should not include the single space between blocks).

**Expected Output using sed**:

`**** **** **** 1234
**** **** **** 2234
**** **** **** 1232
**** **** **** 1232`

**My approach**: I use negative lookbehind(I know that sed does not support lookaround assertions) `\d{4}(?! {2,})` that matches, in first three lines, only the first three block of digits but in the fourth line matches all the blocks of digits(obviously as the last line does not have 2 spaces after the last digit.)

Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/VzQf3D/2

Comment: Please show us the expected output in code tags too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have added a fiddle. Don't wish to use awk. My task is to replace each digit in first three blocks in each line with asterisk using sed.

Comment: I still didn't see expected output, please add it in your post in code tags.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I added the expected output. But I only want the required match in regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Perl, I would say:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d{4})(?= [^ ])/****/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you can try

```
sed ':A;s/\(.*\)\([^ |\*]\)\([ |\*]*[ ][^ ][^ ]*[ ]*$\)/\1*\3/;tA' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 'h;s/^(([^ ]+ ){3})//;x;s/[^ ]*$//;s/[0-9]/*/g;G;s/\n//' file
```

Output:

```
**** **** **** 1234
**** **** **** 2234
**** **** **** 1232
**** **** **** 1232
```

---

See: `man sed`

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about bash, but for normal regex I would use

```
^(?: *)(\d{4})(?: +)(\d{4})(?: +)(\d{4})  # with multiline flag
```

Explanation:

```
^ is line start 
(?: *) is a non capturing group of any number of spaces
(\d{4}) is a capturing group of 4 digit
(?: +) is a non capturing group of one or more number of spaces
(\d{4}) is a capturing group of 4 digit
(?: +) is a non capturing group of one or more number of spaces
(\d{4}) is a capturing group of 4 digit
```

Fiddle: https://regexr.com/3ike0

---

If you use `sed` for this regex, non-capturing groups are not a possibility according to

[how do you specify non-capturing groups in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823864/how-do-you-specify-non-capturing-groups-in-sed)

answer by https://stackoverflow.com/a/36546377/7505395 as well as others provided for this question. Sorry.

Comment: Your solution works good but it matches even single spaces between the blocks. My apologies, I later edited the question to include it.

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma - changed it to ignore the spaces - see fiddle

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma and updated the explanation. You find each number without spaces in seperate groups of the regex match per line

Comment: Your solution captures the spaces too. It should not capture the spaces, only the blocks of digits(4 digits in each block) should be matched.

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma it does NOT capture spaces. For regex there is a "Match" and "Groups" - the "Groups" are where the captured things land - the "Match" is the whole **including** Non-Capuring Groups - by using the values from the "Groups" you get the real captured things - without spaces. Not sure about bash - what bash command are you using with this RegEx pattern?

Comment: Currently I am not using any bash command. I test it on regex101.com, there it (non capturing group `(?: +)`) matches the spaces too(highlighted in blue, whereas spaces _should not be highlighted at all_). I understand your explanation of "Match" and "Group". Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/VzQf3D/3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162220/discussion-between-harshvardhansharma-and-patrick-artner).

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown us expected output so putting this solution as per your explanation only. I believe you need first 3 columns in each line of your Input_file if yes then following may help you in same. If your requirement is different then kindly do show us the expected output with few more details in code tags in your post.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1234 5678 9101
2999 5178 9101
9999 5628 9201
8888 3678 9101
```

***EDIT:*** Seen your edited post, in case you don't need space between 3 columns in output then following may help you in same.

```
awk '{print $1 $2 $3}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
^(?:(?:^| +)[0-9]{4})(?=[0-9]{4} $)
```